# How to create a Facebook app without a website?

Tags: facebook

Might be too basic but bear with me.

It says [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart)  that you need a Callback URL (HTTPS) to setup a webhook, which means you'd need a website of your app with an SSL certificate. Localhost or blog sites etc. won't work.

I feel like this is too much just to build/test an app (without launching it). Is there a way to build/test apps on FB platform without having to buy domain, hosting, SSL certificate for your website?

Comment: No, you can not test Webhooks without a domain with a valid SSL certificate.